# What are Reiju's powers

Tags: one-piece

In the Wholecake island arc, Reiju was able to suck out poison from Luffy's body. How come? Wasn't Impel Down's Magellan the one who ate the Poison-Poison fruit? So what are Reiju's powers?

Comment: That's one of the issues of the Germa characters. We know that their powers don't come from Devil fruits but from experiments and technology, though it is possible that she may have a fruit as we haven't seen her in waste high water to know if it affects her. In the next issue I'm expecting to see more combat panels from the Germa characters and maybe I can answer then.

Comment: check [this](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vinsmoke_Reiju#Abilities_and_Powers), about **poison pink**

Comment: @kaz - I just said that we know that Magellan is the one who ate the Poison fruit

Comment: That doesn't mean anything, so what he ate the poison fruit. There are tons of possibilities that she has a negation fruit, a heal fruit, a drain fruit, or some other fruit power that let's get absorb parts of  some one else. All of which can be associated to fruits

Comment: @mirroroftruth - post an answer to accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Till now(manga chapter 883) we don't know about the devil fruit that Reiju ate, but as described in [one piece wika](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vinsmoke_Reiju#Abilities_and_Powers)

> Possibly resulting from her genetic enhancements, Reiju wields considerable poison-based powers, which garnered her the epithet of "Poison Pink."She can suck poison out of people via mouth-to-mouth and ingest it, while having exhibited immense immunity to the most virulent of poisons, such as extremely lethal doses of the poison from an Armored Stonefish's skin, as shown when she saved Luffy.

And

> Reiju is also capable of secreting poison from her body and combining it with physical attacks.

That may be the reason why Reiju was able to suck out poison from Luffy's body and had no effect on her body.

Comment: According to One Piece Magazine, Reiju did eat a Devil Fruit. We simply don't know yet if her ability to suck out poison is possible thanks to it, or her genetic experiments.